# Filter by UserProfile fields with sfGuard plugin

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard

How do I filter by the sfGuardUserProfile fields, when using the sfGuard plugin in Symfony 1.4?

As I think is standard, I created a sf_guard_user_profile table to hold fields like first name, last name, and so on.

I have a fairly stock list of users for my admin index page. I can filter by the username just fine. But I cannot filter by a field that is in the sf_guard_user_profile table, like last_name.

My generator.yml looks like

```
generator:
  class: sfPropelGenerator
  param:
    model_class: sfGuardUser

    config:
      list:
        display: [=username, first_name, last_name, last_login, role]
        batch_actions: []

      filter:
        display: [username]

      form:
        class: myGuardUserAdminForm
```

I can get the fields to show up in the form on the page by changing to:

```
filter:
    class: sfGuardUserProfileFormFilter
```

but when I submit that form with a valid value for last_name, it doesn't filter. All records are returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `sfGuardUserProfileFormFilter` as filter class isn't the right way to filter first_name, last_name and other profile fields.

Instead you have to add a field, that you need to filter, in the filter display list like:

```
filter:
    display: [username, first_name, last_name]
```

Then you have to merge `sfGuardUserProfileFormFilter` in `sfGuardUserFormFilter`:

```
public function configure()
{
    parent::configure();

    $this->mergeForm(new sfGuardUserProfileFormFilter());
}
```

Finally add in `sfGuardUserFormFilter` a function `addMyFieldColumnCriteria` (Propel notation) for each field of the merged form `sfGuardUserProfileFormFilter` that you want to filter. For first_name we have:

```
    protected function addFirstNameColumnCriteria(Criteria $criteria, $field, $values)
    {
        if (!is_array($values))
            return;

        $criteria->addJoin(sfGuardUserPeer::ID, sfGuardUserProfilePeer::USER_ID, Criteria::INNER_JOIN);

        if (isset($values['is_empty']) && $values['is_empty'])
        {
            $criteria->add($field, null, Criteria::ISNULL);
            $criteria->addOr($field, '', Criteria::EQUAL);
        }
        else
        {
            $value = $values['text'];
            if ($value == '')
                return;
            $criteria->add($field, '%'.$value.'%', Criteria::LIKE);
        }
    }
```